# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'clsData' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying multiple options to solve this and have referred lots of links here and in the net, but could not solve this.

1. I have given BindingResult in controller
2. I have tried with both commanName and modelAttribute in jsp
3. In the ModelMap object I tried to add bean object
4. I also gave separate definitions for get and post request and added the bean object in get request
5. I hope I have given correct path for base package “com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web”
6. Correct ModelAndView import “import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView”

Still I am missing something . pls help

ClsEditBody.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<form:form action="/ClsSave" method="POST" modelAttribute="clsData" onsubmit="return CheckPassword()">
       <form:hidden path="ukey" />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="100%" class="form">   
           <tr>
<td align=left valign=top><tlc:text tabindex="1" size="29" maxlength="26" property="Name"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

tradelc-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

       <context:annotation-config />
       <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure-->
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="messageSource"
              class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
              <property name="basename" value="resources.application" />
       </bean>


       <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="viewClass"
                     value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
       </bean>
</beans>
```

ClsSaveAction.java:

```
@Controller
public class ClsSaveAction implements OMXServiceIDs {
       @RequestMapping(value = "/ClsSave", method = RequestMethod.GET)
          public ModelAndView ClsSave(Object command) throws Exception{
              ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("ClsSave");
              mv.addObject("clsData", new ClauseData());
              return mv;

             //return new ModelAndView("ClsEdit", "command", new ClauseData());
          }
@RequestMapping(value = "/ClsSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView execute(HttpServletRequest  request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                 @ModelAttribute("clsData") ClauseData clauseData,
                                 BindingResult bindingResult,
                                 Model model)
        throws Exception {
        //DynaActionForm daform  = (DynaActionForm) form;
              model.addAttribute("clsData", new ClauseData());
.
.
.
.
.
.
return new ModelAndView("Main", "clsData", new ClauseData());
}
}
}
```

Project structure:

```
Src/main/java
|
|
com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.actions
|
       ClsSaveAction.java
|
com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.bean
|      
       ClauseData.java
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'clsData' available as request attribute
        org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:79)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
        org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f0(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:356)
        org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:255)
        org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspx_meth_tlc_005fin_005f0(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:214)
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon submitting your form will try to bind the form input values to the properties of your *clsData* bean. This means that the bean must be already in the model when you render the JSP with the form.

In the controller handler that forwards to your *ClsEditBody* you should add the *ClauseData* bean in a model, something like

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/ClsEdit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView clsEdit() throws Exception{
          new ModelAndView("ClsEditBody", "clsData", new ClauseData());
      }
```

*UPDATE after additional info*

The code that you provided in the answer will work, but in addition you should also annotate the *InformLoginAction* controller with `@SessionAttributes("clsData")`. And add a model attribute method to your InformLoginAction controller. It will ensure that the binding command object is in place when you render the form.

```
@ModelAttribute("clsData")
public ClauseData createBean() {
    return new ClauseData();
}
```

the model attribute method *createBean* would be called on every request, before the handler method is called, but since you use @SessionAttribute with the matching *clsData* key, the method will be called only once, and the bean will be taken from session attributes on the subsequent calls

Comment: Added this `@SessionAttributes("clsData")
public class InformLoginAction {...`. Tried with this also `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("menu");
        modelAndView.addObject("clsData", new ClauseData());
        return modelAndView;`. No luck. Please help

Comment: I added the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. In my ClsEditBody.jsp i printed the clsData object `System.out.println(session.getAttribute("clsData").toString());` and it printed `com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.bean.ClauseData@cbb9c6`. Does that mean that my clsData object is available for use in ClsEditBody.jsp, but still i am getting this exception? Any pointers pls...